# How to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning when setting a single value?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I avoid the warning `SettingWithCopyWarning` in this case?

Normally, it is enough to use a `copy()` of a previously created DataFrame. This does not make sense in this situation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [7, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "c": [np.nan, np.nan, np.NaN]})
df.c.iloc[0] = 100
```

.

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution if default `RangeIndex` is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with specify index and column value:

```
df.loc[0, 'c'] = 100
print (df)
   a  b      c
0  7  4  100.0
1  2  5    NaN
2  3  6    NaN
```

If want set by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is necessry  [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `c`:

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('c')] = 100
```